# change/load events broke after keydown Escape event

Tags: javascript

I have input type=file for upload pictures and modal element, where this picture will appear. When 'change' occured, add listener for FileReader 'load'. When file loaded, we can see modal element with picture and close btn. At the end upload function added modal close listeners.
When I am use click on close btn, its work, even if I pick same picture to upload.
But after Escape keydown event, showModal didnt work with the same picture. Why is there two difference behaviors?
PS sry English

```
const hideByEsc = (evt) => {
      if (evt.key === 'Escape') {
        hideModal();
        document.body.removeEventListener('keydown', hideByEsc);
      }
    };
    
    const hideByClick = () => {
      hideModal();
      closeBtn.removeEventListener('click', hideByClick);
    };
    
    const showModal = () => {
      imgUploadOverlay.classList.remove('hidden');
      document.body.classList.add('modal-open');
      closeBtn.addEventListener('click', hideByClick);
      document.body.addEventListener('keydown', hideByEsc);
    };
    
    const uploadFile = () => {
      inputUpload.addEventListener('change', () => {
        console.log('I am in change upload');
        const reader = new FileReader();
        const inputFile = inputUpload.files[0];
        reader.addEventListener('load', () => {
          console.log('I am in load reader');
          if (TYPES.includes(inputFile.type)) {
            imgUploadPreview.src = reader.result;
            showModal();
          }
        });
        reader.readAsDataURL(inputFile);
      });
    };
    
    uploadFile();
```

Comment: at first check, whether your escape event works or not (simple check just by console or alert).